# GPU rendering images with Python cv2 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, gpu

I am using the Raspberry Pi 2 to load large resolution images using opencv. I have sketch running, but without apparent "OpenGL" support as the opencv library states that it is not supported:

```
OpenCV Error: no OpenGL support (Library was built without openGL support)
```

I attempted to install pyOpenGL, but this had no effect. I am pretty new to graphics programming, so I'd take any suggestions on how to render to the GPU of the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Raspberry Pi has a really crappy GPU. As far as I know, it only supports OpenGL ES which won't cut it.

Comment: As I understand it, the Pi has no support for OpenCL or CUDA, the two options for easy GPU processing. OpenGL ES does support shaders however, so you would be able to do it the very difficult/old fashioned way in c/c++. Not sure how one would go about taking that route in Python though.

Comment: I found Pi3D library was the best approach

Comment: this might help for camera images http://robotblogging.blogspot.com.au/2013/10/gpu-accelerated-camera-processing-on.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ive stumbled across a Python friendly module that contains a GLSL API with quite a bit of examples :

http://pi3d.github.io/html/

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to deal with the gpu. Try following [this blog](http://robertcastle.com/2014/02/installing-opencv-on-a-raspberry-pi/), as it seems to have OpenCV install instructions. You might want to set INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES ON, but that is the only difference I could see.

Then you should be able to use it with python. If not, you may need to add it to your PATH.